# Find linear transformation of unknowns

Tags: matrices, vectors

Find linear transformation of unknowns, that makes quadratic forms canonical, defined by own matrices. Decide, does quadratic form have property of having fixed sign.
\begin{vmatrix} 
2 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
-1 & 2 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Is this question translated from some other language than English?

Comment: yes, from russian

Comment: @XqwWeqaf Try editing your the question in Russian into this question then (you might want to keep the English as well).  There are several people on this site who speak other languages and you might get a response or at least someone might be able to translate it into English a little better.